# d3.js using a conditional return within text attribute

Tags: d3.js

I have a legend which returns the 2 column names from my dataset 'data2'.

This function returns the text:

```
.text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
```

Rather than changing the names of my columns is there a way to conditionally change the text.   Eg   when column = A then use "Field1" else "Field2"

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(data2)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .style("font-family", "raleway")
  .style("font-size", "8")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/ua3L7sv8/8/) added

Comment: I'd advice adjusting your data format. Instead of having `d` be text, change it to be object, eg `{ field: 'A', legend: 'Field1' }`. Putting as you want in an if inside of text function would make your data scattered and brittle for change

Comment: Could you share some sample/dummy data?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino  thanks.    This sounds interesting.   Would I make this change within the text attribute itself or within the dataset?

Comment: @Coola   Here is a fiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/ua3L7sv8/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a conditional return statement within the function which returns d. For example:

```
  .text(function(d) {
    if (d==="A") {
        return "Field1" 
    }else {
        return "Field2"
    }
  })
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolakul/jq7o84hL/).

Let me know if this is not the solution you were looking for.